# Is it possible to extract the IPTC information of many scans programmatically?

Tags: metadata, batch, software-recommendation

I have several hundred jpeg-scans of negatives. For some of these, I stored a textual description of the picture in the Caption-field of the IPTC metadata. (Whether it was a clever idea to store it there or elsewhere is a different question). I need a way to programmatically get out the text from all scans.

I.e. what I need is a tool which dumps the IPTC of all negatives programmatically. I can access the IPTC info in Irfanview by clicking buttons, but this is not practicable for more than a handful of scans. It needs to be programmatically in batch, ideally on the command line / bash shell, ideally with ASCII ouput.

Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of free and open source tools that will do this, for Linux, Mac, or Windows. If you just need something very simple, [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) should do. Put it in a loop  and output the result to one or more text files.

If you need more sophisticated options, you can step up to one of [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) or [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). These can read and write all sorts of metadata, including IPTC captions. Both programs are good. Exiv2 might be a little faster and is easier to embed in C programs, but that doesn't really affect you. ExifTool is probably more full-featured, but I don't think it'll matter for your basically-simple use case. Take a look at the docs and pick whichever seems easier to you.